# how to sort a list while prioritizing alphabets before numbers?

Tags: tcl

My list is:

```
set list {23 12 5 20 one two three four}
```

The expected output is in the increasing order, the difference is that alphabets need to be put at the beginning:

```
four one three two 12 20 23 5
```

I tried the following:

```
# sorting the list in increasing order:
lsort -increasing $list
-> 12 20 23 5 four one three two
# Here i get the result with numbers first as the ascii value of numbers are higher than alphabets.
```

```
lsort -decreasing $list
# -> two three one four 5 23 20 12
```

Comment: Do you also want the numbers sorted as numbers instead of as strings? (i.e. 5 before 12)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest wring a comparator:

```
proc compareItm {a b} {
    set aIsInt [string is integer $a]
    set bIsInt [string is integer $b]

    if {$aIsInt == $bIsInt} {
        # both are either integers or both are not integers - default compare
        # but force string compare
        return [string compare $a $b]
        # if you want 5 before 12, comment the line above and uncomment the following line
        # return [expr {$a < $b ? -1 : $a > $b ? 1 : 0}]
    } else {
        return [expr {$aIsInt - $bIsInt}]
    }
}
```

And use it with the `-command` option of `lsort`:

```
lsort -command compareItm
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways is to produce *collation keys* and sort by those:

```
lmap pair [lsort -index 1 [lmap item $list {
    list $item [expr {[string is integer $item] ? "Num:$item" : "Let:$item"}]
}]] {lindex $pair 0}
```

If you're using Tcl 8.5 or 8.4 (which lack `lmap`), you do this with a more long-winded version:

```
set temp {}
foreach item $list {
    lappend temp [list $item [expr {
        [string is integer $item] ? "Num:$item" : "Let:$item"
    }]]
}
set result {}
foreach pair [lsort -index 1 $temp] {
    lappend result [lindex $pair 0]
}
```